# IOException: Cannot determine the frame size or a corrupted frame was received

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5, asp.net-core-5.0

Please explain why this doesn't work with "https://localhost:5001" but works correctly with "https://localhost:44386". If you will send a link to any documentation, it will be large plus.

1. 2 asp.net core 5.0 WebAPI applications
2. one application sends an http request to another
3. throwing an exception in the first option

   ```
   public class SomeHttpClient: ISomeHttpClient
   {
       private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

       public ServerHealthCheckServiceHttpClient(HttpClient httpClient, IOptions<SomeOptions> options)
       {
           _httpClient = httpClient;
           _httpClient.BaseAddress = options.Value.SomeAddress;
       }

       public async Task<bool> DoSomething(CancellationToken token)
       {
           var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "someMethod");
           var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request, token);
       }
   }
   ```

First variant error `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> System.IO.IOException: Cannot determine the frame size or a corrupted frame was received.`

Comment: Could you please [have a look here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/22563). You might need to [modify like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/5.0/kestrel-default-supported-tls-protocol-versions-changed).

Answer (score 0):

Change port number. That will unblock you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).